# 1/10 returns value 0 but if we take modulus 1%10, it returns 1?

Tags: java, operators

Arithmetic Divide operator **/** returns the Quotient while Arithmetic modulus operator **%** returns the Remainder. What can be the reason when divide operator is used, it returns 0 value and modulus operator % returns 1. The expression is 1/10 and 1%10.

- **Note: I am using data type Integer: "int"**

Answer (score 1):

Like you said modulus is returning the remaining of a division.

As example:

1 % 10 = 0 R **1**  <- This is the value Java returns

15 % 10 = 1 R **5** <- Here it returns 5 because it couldn't divide anymore

And 1 / 10 returns 0 because you are only using Integers. If you doesn't use a floating point number it doesn't return one and rounds down the result.

So if you want a floating point number you will need something like that:

```
    System.out.println(1 / 10); // -> 0
    
    System.out.println((float) 1 / 10);   // -> 0.1 //You can also use double for casting
    System.out.println(1.0 / 10);         // -> 0.1
    System.out.println(1 / 10.0);         // -> 0.1
    System.out.println(1.0 / 10.0);       // -> 0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, It has nothing to do with coding.
We can simply understand it by solving basic maths.
As we know:

```
Dividend / Divisor == > we get 2 Answers 
          Quotient and Remainder
```

If the Remainder is 0, the Dividend is completely divided by Divisor
with parts of Quotient.

As in your suggested example,
1/10 actual Answer is 0.1 which is a float,

In your Java code, you must be looking for the integer value, which practically is not possible.

And obviously, 1%10 will give you 1,
as 10 as divisor can not divide 1 as a dividend.

You can try it with a float variable. I hope you will get your expected results.